# Running browsermob with selenium grid on docker

Tags: python, selenium, docker, browsermob, browsermob-proxy

I am using the python client for browsermob to record traffic of my selenium tests. Selenium grid is in a docker container with images for chrome and firefox. I cant seem to configure the docker images properly to connect to the proxy and the grid.
Here is the code that I use to create the proxy and the remote web driver:

```
server = browsermobproxy.Server('mylocalpathtobrowsermobbin')
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
proxy.new_har()
driver = webdriver.Remote(
                command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
                desired_capabilities={
                    'browserName': 'chrome',
                    'chromeOptions': {
                        'args': ["--proxy-server={}".format(proxy.proxy)]}
                    })
```

And this is my docker-compose file:

```
hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
     - "4444:4444"
chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
  volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  links:
    - hub
  ports:
    - "5900:5900"
```

I am new to docker, I understand that I need to expose the port that the proxy uses to connect but I cannot get it working. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: where is the code running?

Comment: Right now its running locally, both the test and the docker images, eventually it will run on jenkins CI which is pretty much the same setup as my local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Answer my own question based on the response from Sergey:
I pushed a browsermob-proxy image to docker hub:
https://hub.docker.com/r/spothero/browsermob-proxy/

created from this repository:
https://github.com/sskorol/docker-browsermob-proxy

All credit goest to Sergey for the docker file.

My docker compose file:

```
hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
     - "4444:4444"
firefox:
  image: selenium/node-firefox
  links:
    -  hub
chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
  volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  links:
    - hub
  ports:
    - "5900:5900"
browsermobproxy:
  image: spothero/browsermob-proxy:1.0.0
  ports:
    - "9090-9191:9090-9191"
  expose:
    - "9090-9191"
  links:
    - hub
    - firefox
    - chrome
```

On the jenkins job I have a shell step:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
sleep 10s

PROXY_IP_ADDRESS="$(docker inspect --format {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}} browsermobproxy_1)"
export BROWSERMOB_CONTAINER_HOST=$PROXY_IP_ADDRESS
```

I use an environment variable to pass the hosts to my test code.
Here is the code that initializes the webdriver with the proxy:

```
    import browsermobproxy
    self.client = browsermobproxy.Client('localhost:9090')
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=settings.SELENIUM_GRID_HUB,
        desired_capabilities={
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': {
                'args': ["--proxy-server={}".format(
                    os.environ.get('BROWSERMOB_CONTAINER_HOST'), self.client.port)]
            }
        })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @eduardoreynoso, i have used above mentioned dockerfile. Using this I am able to start browsermob and grid. However when I tried ur code to initialise webdriver its failing. As i am providing ip of browsermob docker container instead of localhost. Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to raise BMP in a container as well. And then link it with a grid. Check this [article](https://sskorol.github.io/2016/07/18/Tracking-tests-network-statistics-with-Docker.html) to get the idea and key implementation / configuration points.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I used the article and the link to your implementation I managed to get it working, once I have a minute I will post a full answer for other people to see. Thanks again!